# How can I debug my apps wireless if IP address is unavailable?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I followed all instructions found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb, still can't find my device's IP address, because it's unavailable:

[image: Screen status]

[image: Screen WI-FI]

What could I possible do? I don't want to root my phone, and I can't run the emulator on low-end PC. And BTW I'm using Alcatel... The USB cable was borrowed... Please, help!

Comment: for wireless debugging to work phone and pc should be on same network. are you sure you are connected to wifi?

Comment: So there should be the third device, that should be the hotspot (WI-FI)? Both my phone and PC connect to it? But... In my country, we use more mobile broadband...

Comment: you can create hotspot from mobile and connect your laptop to that hotspot

Comment: You dont need internet for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For wireless debugging to work phone and pc should be on same network. So one thing you can do is to create hotspot from mobile and connect your laptop to that hotspot.(You don't need internet for that)
When you get connected to a network IP address is assigned to your device.

Comment: When I remove USB, the connection is lost... And earlier as success confirmation I received: connected to 10.42.0.142:5555. Any solution?